# Validation error on device extension on M1 mac

Tags: macos, vulkan, moltenvk

So I am attempting to follow the Vulkan tutorial on a mac with an M1 processor, and I am running into an issue with device creation.

So as per [the tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Logical_device_and_queues) I am setting the device enabled extensions like so:

```
const std::vector<const char*> deviceExtensions = {
    VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME,
};

VkDeviceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(deviceExtensions.size());
createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = deviceExtensions.data();
```

When I run this, I get the following validation errors:

> validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkDeviceCreateInfo-pProperties-04451 ] Object 0: handle = 0x11bd84d40, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x3a3b6ca0 | vkCreateDevice: VK_KHR_portability_subset must be enabled because physical device VkPhysicalDevice 0x11bd84d40[] supports it The Vulkan spec states: If the VK_KHR_portability_subset extension is included in pProperties of vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties, ppEnabledExtensionNames must include "VK_KHR_portability_subset" (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.211.0/mac/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkDeviceCreateInfo-pProperties-04451)

> validation layer: vkCreateDevice: Attempting to create a VkDevice from a VkPhysicalDevice which is from a portability driver without the VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR bit in the VkInstanceCreateInfo flags being set and the VK_KHR_portability_enumeration extension enabled. In future versions of the loader this VkPhysicalDevice will not be enumerated.

So I have tried adding the `VK_KHR_portability_subset` extension mentioned in the first error:

```
const std::vector<const char*> deviceExtensions = {
    VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME,
    "VK_KHR_portability_subset",
};
```

And then I get the following validation errors:

> validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-vkCreateDevice-ppEnabledExtensionNames-01387 ] Object 0: handle = 0x106849800, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE; | MessageID = 0x12537a2c | Missing extension required by the device extension VK_KHR_portability_subset: VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2. The Vulkan spec states: All required device extensions for each extension in the VkDeviceCreateInfo::ppEnabledExtensionNames list must also be present in that list (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.211.0/mac/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCreateDevice-ppEnabledExtensionNames-01387)

> validation layer: vkCreateDevice: Attempting to create a VkDevice from a VkPhysicalDevice which is from a portability driver without the VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR bit in the VkInstanceCreateInfo flags being set and the VK_KHR_portability_enumeration extension enabled. In future versions of the loader this VkPhysicalDevice will not be enumerated.

> validation layer: vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR: Emulation found unrecognized structure type in pProperties->pNext - this struct will be ignored

So it looks like it's missing the `VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2` and I tried adding that as well:

```
const std::vector<const char*> deviceExtensions = {
    VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME,
    "VK_KHR_portability_subset",
    "VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2"
};
```

And after adding this, device creation actually fails with this error:

> validation layer: loader_validate_device_extensions: Device extension VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2 not supported by selected physical device or enabled layers.

So it seems like it's impossible to satisfy the validation layers.  What's the correct way to initialize a logical device on an M1 mac?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It does work for me, but ...

you have to add VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME in VkInstanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames when creating the Vulkan instance first (the vkCreateInstance call), before creating the device, together with whatever other extensions you are using:

```
VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo{};

...

const std::vector<const char*> exts =
{
    ...
    VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_EXT_METAL_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_MVK_MACOS_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME,    
    VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME, // <--
    ...
};

ppEnabledExtensionNames = exts.data();

...
```

and also add the flag bit that validation layer also tells you about:

```
createInfo.flags = VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR;
```

Create the instance and then DON'T include VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2, but add VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_SUBSET_EXTENSION_NAME when you create the device and you are done.

All this seems to be needed starting with 1.3.216.0 Vulkan SDK.

Comment: VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_SUBSET_EXTENSION_NAME is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The key observation is that the error message (likely autogenerated) is wrong. `VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2` is an **instance** extension and not a device extension. Thus the solution is to define `VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2` and `VK_KHR_portability_enumeration` in your instance extensions and define `VK_KHR_portability_subset` in your device extensions. Doing this, I was able to make the error message go away.

Comment: P.S. In the future you can always verify whether an extension is device or instance-specific by running `vulkaninfo`. It presents you a list of both the device and instance extensions available on your platform.